# Где может использоваться .* и ->*?

Tags: c++, указатели, c++-faq

То есть `.*` - доступ к указателю на член класса и `->*` - доступ к указателю на член класса по указателю. Покажите на примерах.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот далеко не полный список примеров:

- [с сайта МС](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx)
- [большая статья на codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible)
- [аналогичный вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586205/what-are-the-pointer-to-member-and-operators-in-c)
- [ещё один](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member)

да, все это на английском, но там есть примеры на с++, а он как известно и в Африке с++.

Comment: Еще раз убеждаюсь, что изучение С++ - дело всей жизни )))

Comment: Да, век живи - век учись. А ведь без практики все равно через месяц забуду, что так можно вызывать.

Comment: [KoVadim][1], Спасибо за ссылки. В последней нашел [этот][2] пост, пожалуй с ним и буду ассоциировать целесообразность применения, пока не встречу что-то ещё на практике.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/2739/kovadim
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member/670743#670743

Answer (score 6):

Простенький пример:

```
class My{
  void(My::*z)( int );
  //
  void state_1( int x ){ if( x == 1 ){ z = &My::state_2; } }
  void state_2( int x ){ if( x == 2 ){ z = &My::state_3; }else{ z = &My::state_1; } }
  void state_3( int x ){ if( x == 3 ){ z = &My::state_1; } }
  //
public:
  My( void ) : z( &My::state_1 ){}
  void state( int x ){
    (this->*z)( x );
  }
};
```

Здесь, в классе `My` имеется поле `z`, которое хранит текущее состояние объекта класса `My`. В зависимости от внешнего воздействия `x`, это состояние может меняться.

Вот так обычная стейт-машина может становиться более понятной с "указателями на члены класса".

Answer (score -2):

Оператор (.) точка применяется к обычным объектам, например:

```
class C{
pubic:
  int value;
  int method();
};

int main()...
  C c; // объект
  c.value = 3; // обращение к данным
  c.method(); // вызов метода
```

то же относится к структурам:

```
struct C{
pubic:
  int value;
  int method();
};

int main()...
  C c; // обьект
  c.value = 3; // обращение к данным
  c.method(); // вызов метода
```

к объектам находящихся в памяти используется оператор (->) стрелка:

```
class C{
pubic:
  int value;
  int method();
};

int main()...
  C * p; // указатель на обьект
  p = new C; // создаем объект в памяти
  c->value = 3; // обращение к данным
  c->method(); // вызов метода
```

то же относится к структурам:

```
 struct C{
    pubic:
      int value;
      int method();
    };

int main()...
  C * p; // указатель на обьект
  p = new C; // создаем объект в памяти
  c->value = 3; // обращение к данным
  c->method(); // вызов метода
```

оператор (->) стрелка применяется так же внутри класса к указателю (this), например:

```
class C{
    pubic:
      int value;
      int method(){
        this->value = 10; // указатель на себя
      }
};
```

Comment: this->value = 10;  
А зачем такое нужно? По сути же при компиляции, классов не останется, а будут функции со скрытым параметром *this и он сам подставится под переменные, к примеру просто написать value и будет работать, а дальше компилятор подставит this->value, то есть разницы нет и если не указанно явно, то компилятор подставит неявно. Правильно ли я понял? Или есть случаи когда такое нужно указывать явно? А то я видел только как через *this возвращается объект.

Comment: например мы перегружаем оператор (=) равно. Чтоб убедится что объект не копирует самого себя можно проверит адрес объектов справа и лево от оператора (=) равно

Comment: @perfect, а Вы вопрос внимательно прочитали?

Comment: нет неправильно. прочитал только заголовок. извиняюсь

Comment: ну в общем тогда отвечу так что оператор (->) заменяет (.*) и всего то