# Поле класса - указатель на метод

Tags: c++, указатели

Здравствуйте!

В [одном из ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/196690/c-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8) увидел, что поле класса определяется таким образом:

```
    void(My::*z)( int );
```

Поясните, пожалуйста такую запись. В каких случаях она используется?

Comment: Указатель на один из методов класса My, принимающий аргумент типа int, который ничего не возвращает.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. А вот так значит присваивается указателю определенная функция
z = &My::state_2;
А в этом месте вызвали функцию state_2 (this->*z)( x );

Верно? Спасибо

Comment: Верно, только вызвали не `state_2`, а вызвали ту, на которую указывает `z` на данный момент. Это может быть `state_1`, `state_2` или `state_3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> В каких случаях она используется?

Такое поле используется в случаях, когда есть какая-то внешняя зависимость на метод класса. В моем примере эта зависимость от внутреннего состояния объекта. Без "указателя на метод" все равно пришлось бы вводить дополнительную переменную `State`. Но в таком случае, логика метода была бы не так очевидна.

Вот тот же пример без `z`:

```
class My{
  int State;
public:
  My( void ) : State( 0 ){}
  void state( int x ){
    switch( State ){
      case 0:
        if( x == 1 ){ State = 1; }
        break;
      case 1:
        if( x == 2 ){ State = 2; }else{ State = 1; }
        break;
      case 2:
        if( x == 3 ){ State = 0; }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Очевидно, в таком варианте запутаться в номерах состояний гораздо проще, чем в исходном. Для лучшей ориентации по коду в таких случаях вводят `enum`:

```
class My{
  enum{
    state_1 = 0,
    state_2,
    state_3
  };
  int State;
public:
  My( void ) : State( state_1 ){}
  void state( int x ){
    switch( State ){
      case state_1:
        if( x == 1 ){ State = state_2; }
        break;
      case state_2:
        if( x == 2 ){ State = state_3; }else{ State = state_1; }
        break;
      case 2:
        if( x == 3 ){ State = state_1; }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Но на мой взгляд, даже в таком случае исходный вариант выгоднее для понимания.

Comment: Супер! Спасибо Вам.